# Should I be able to run these postgresql statements in client tools?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, dbeaver

Please, understand that I am totally new to Postgresql.  I am having trouble testing queries in client tools like pgAdmin and DBeaver.

This works:

```
select * 
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE  schemaname = 'schema_name' 
   AND tablename  = 'table_name'
```

But not this:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Hi' ;
```

I also can't run anything with an "if" statement.  I have years of experience with SSMS, and so I expect to be able to run statements like this.  Am I using the tool wrong or are they just not capable of these types of statements?  Thank you.

Comment: It's not the tool. RAISE NOTICE and IF only work in [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) procedural code, not in SQL statements.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm, are there any tools for Postgresql that are equivalent to SSMS for SQL Server that let you run procedural code?

Comment: Both pgAdmin and DBeaver will allow you to run procedural code. You have to use _valid_ PL/pgSQL code though, i.e. either inside a stored procedure/function or inside a [do block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html)

Comment: Any PostgreSQL tool can run procedural code, just use valid code. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @a_horse_with_no_name.  I needed to be using a [do block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'my message';
END; $$;


DO $$
begin
IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_tables WHERE  schemaname = 'schema_name' AND tablename  = 'table_name') then    
     RAISE NOTICE 'exists' ;   
ELSE    
     RAISE NOTICE 'not exists' ;  
end IF;
END; $$;
```